# How to get full language mode when remoting

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm performing some powershell remoting. The systems in question have SMB access disabled, so I can't use direct access to the files in question. As a result, I've been using the ps session to copy files.

```
$remote_session = New-PSSession -computername $FromHost
Invoke-Command -Session $remote_session -scriptblock $scriptblock -ArgumentList xxxxx
Copy-Item -FromSession $remote_session "C:\xxxx\$FileName" "C:\yyyyy\$FileName" -verbose
Remove-PSSession $remote_session
```

Recently I'm getting failures on specific machines, and I've narrowed it down to constrained language mode on the remote endpoint.

If I'm working locally I can get full language mode by signing a script.. how do I do this remotely? The cert I have authorizes full language mode on the remote machine... I'm just not sure how to pass that info along.